# Can't run "npm start" "ENOENT [...] This is related to npm not being able to find a file"

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

*I am new to coding, so my apologies if there is something too obvious here or that I am not providing*

Yesterday I was learning GraphQL, so I installed the package "express-graphql".

Since yesterday, whenever I try to run "npm start" I get the same error (on any project, even projects that worked just fine before yesterday):

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Code\express
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

For context:

- Before yesterday, npm start worked just fine. Now, it's not working on any project, seems to be related to npm as a whole...?
- I have try to reinstall nodejs. Nothing changed.
- Package.json is there, in the root directory of the project as it should be, and has the script "start":"node server.js"
- In case it helps, here is one of the projects that before worked perfectly and now don't: https://github.com/RicSala/express
- I can do npm install normally, no problem with that
- node modules folder is there
- I can do "node server.js" instead of trying to user npm scripts, and it works normally.

I am pasting below the error log in case it helps.

```
0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@9.5.0
2 info using node@v18.14.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 2ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 2ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 1ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Code\graphql\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 2ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Ricardo\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 0ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 12ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 12ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 1ms
20 verbose title npm test
21 verbose argv "test"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 2ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-23T08_40_59_863Z-
26 verbose logfile C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-23T08_40_59_863Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 7ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 27ms
31 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
32 timing command:run-script Completed in 12ms
33 timing command:test Completed in 17ms
34 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT
34 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
34 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
34 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
35 verbose pkgid graphql@1.0.0
36 verbose cwd C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Code\graphql
37 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
38 verbose node v18.14.2
39 verbose npm  v9.5.0
40 error code ENOENT
41 error syscall spawn bash
42 error path C:\Users\Ricardo\Desktop\Code\graphql
43 error errno -4058
44 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT
45 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
45 error enoent
46 verbose exit -4058
47 timing npm Completed in 66ms
48 verbose code -4058
49 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
49 error     C:\Users\Ricardo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-23T08_40_59_863Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

Reading the logs, I saw node was trying to use "bash". So instead of using the default VSC terminal, I change to Git Bash.

There it worked just fine.